# Replace string with quotes and slashes

Tags: powershell-3.0

I have the following string in a file:

```
application=\"MyApp\"
```

and I would like to remove it with PowerShell command (or replace with '').

I tried this and it didn't work:

```bsh
powershell -Command "Get-ChildItem -Path ./Transform\*.json -recurse | ForEach {If (Get-Content $_.FullName | Select-String -Pattern ' where useraction.application=\\\"MyApp\\\"') {(Get-Content $_ | ForEach {$_ -replace ' where useraction.application=\\\"MyApp\\\"', ' '}) | Set-Content $_ -encoding UTF8}}"
```

I thought putting a backslash in front of each special charcter would work, but no luck so far.

Comment: Use the `ConvertFrom-Json` and `ConvertTo-Json` cmdlets if you need to manipulate JSON data. For further help please [edit] your question and show sample JSON input.

Comment: @srinivasy Please do not wrap code in arbitrary places. Your edit breaks the OP's code.